# The asymptotic expansion of a particular composition of functions (Berkeley Problems in Mathematics, Problem 1.1.9 (Summer 1981))

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> (Berkeley Problems in Mathematics, Problem 1.1.9 (Summer 1981)) Let $$y(h) = 1 - 2 \sin ^2 (2 \pi h), \quad f(y)= \dfrac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}} .$$
> Justify the statement $$ f(y(h)) = 2 - 4 \sqrt 2 \pi + O(h^2) $$
> where
> $$\limsup _{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{O(h^2)}{h^2} < \infty.$$

1st idea.
$$ g(h) : = f(y(h)) =  \dfrac{2}{1+ \sqrt{1-(1-2 \sin^2 (2 \pi h))^2}} = \dfrac{2}{1+ \sqrt{4 \sin^2 (2 \pi h) - 4 \sin^4 (2 \pi h)}} = \dfrac{2}{1+ 2 \sin (2 \pi h) \sqrt{1-\sin^2(2\pi h)}} = \dfrac{2}{1+ \sin(4 \pi h)},$$
and by Taylor's expansion
$$ g(h) = g(0) + g'(0) h + O(h^2) = 2 - \left. 8 \pi \dfrac{\cos(4 \pi h)}{(1 + \sin 4 \pi h)^2} \right|_{h=0} h+ O(h^2) = 2 - 8 \pi h + O(h^2)  $$
which is not what I was looking for...

---

2nd idea.
By Taylor's expansion
$$ f(y(h)) = f(y(0)) + f'(y(0))y'(0)h + O(h^2) = ??? $$
since $y(0) = 1$ and $\nexists f'(1) $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You solved your "own" problem correctly. However, the problem given in the Berkeley prelim is different:

http://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/Summer81.pdf

Note that $f(y) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-y}}$, not $f(y) = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}$.

Edit: BTW, also, the answer you have in your question right now, i.e. "Justify the statement $f(y(h)) = 2-4\sqrt{2}\pi+O(h^2)$" should read "Justify the statement $f(y(h)) = 2-4\sqrt{2}\pi|h|+O(h^2)$."

Comment: Wow, I copied the problem as it is from "Berkeley problems in mathematics" by de Souza and Silva, trusted it and didn't even check if the text was correct... Thanks!